# Cant access website/images under /var/www/

Tags: html, web-applications

About a year ago I placed some media and some web pages under my

```
/var/www/
```

on my server(I am using ubuntu-server). I was able to access these web pages by going to

```
http://myipaddressgoedhere/pagename
```

recently, I have a need to store media in a folder in

```
/var/www/images
```

when I went to go see if I could still access these web pages store under

```
/var/www/
```

I am unable to hit any of the web pages.

I dont remember changing anything that would allow me not to see .html files in this directory.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What http status code do you receive? What is the result of the `ls -l /var/www` command? Doesn't your question belong to serverfault?

Comment: Its telling me it cannot connect to the server. No status code is provided. I know it is not the connection though, because I can access other web applications on my server.

Comment: It is showing all my files, and they all show all permissions, which I made that way just to ensure that woudn't stop me from accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the dates on any of your .htaccess files have changed (there may be one in each directory) and remember filenames starting with . are hidden in ubuntu by default.

Answer (score 1):

First check the obvious things:

1. Is (i assume) httpd running? Can you access any pages at all or some pages but not others.
2. Are the files still where you left them, have they been moved or deleted?
3. Check the rights of the files and ensure that apache can load them?

Comment: how can I check to see if httpd is running? I have checked that the files are in the same spot, and I have changed the permissions for the files to allow all rwx.

Comment: Try "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop" then "/etc/init.d/apache2 start" or
"/etc/init.d/apache2 restart". THis won't give you a direct answer if it's running or not but will give you more info. This may give you some clues. Alternatively the folks at the Ubuntu forums are very friendly.